# readline in C++?

Tags: c++, readline

I have a text file that I need to read in to variables in my code. For example lets say the `.txt` file looks like:

```
John
Town
12
Mike
Village
22
```

where there is a pattern of name then address then age of multiple people. I found that with (***`***)

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

I can print out each line of the text file, but how could I assign the text to a variable?
I remember in Java you could do something along the lines of

```
while(there is a next line){
    name = something.readline();
    address = something.readline();
    age = something.readline();
    //do something with variables i.e construct new object then 
    //re-loop to construct new object with next set of data
}
```

the trick was that after readline() was called it would then move down a line in the text file and then next variable would be assign to the text below and so on. How can I recreate this in C++?

Comment: 'std::string name, address, age;'

'getline(myfile, name);'
'getline(myfile, address);'
'getline(myfile, age);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do stuff like this, I like to structure my data into records and write a function to read each record rather like this:

```
// logically grouped data
struct record
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    unsigned age;
};

// function to read in one record
// returns std:ostream& so that the while() loop can check
// the stream to make sure the read was successful.
// Takes record as a reference to pass the data back out
// of the function
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, record& r)
{
    std::getline(is, r.name);
    std::getline(is, r.address);
    is >> r.age >> std::ws;
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("example.txt");

    record r;

    while(read(myfile, r)) // while the read was a success
    {
        // do something with record here
        std::cout << "   name: " << r.name << '\n';
        std::cout << "address: " << r.address << '\n';
        std::cout << "    age: " << r.age << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```