# C++ while loop and getline issue

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, getline

I am having an issue with a while loop in a program I am creating.
Basically it is suppose to ask the user for input until ctrl + D is entered (The entries will eventually be stored in an array, but I am just trying to check output before I start on that step)

The issue is when i cout the variables the first line is missing.

```
int main()
{
    string title;
    string url;
    string comment;
    double length = 0.0;
    int rating = 0;
    string sort_method;

    cin >> sort_method;

while(getline(cin,title))
{
        getline(cin, title);
        getline(cin, url);
        getline(cin, comment);
        cin >> length;
        cin >> rating;
        cin.ignore();

}
    cout << title << endl;
    cout << url << endl;
    cout << comment << endl;
    cout << length << endl;
    cout << rating << endl;
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You're reading the title twice. Remove the `getline(cin,title);` **inside** the while body (leave the one in the while-conditional). And move the while-loop closing curly *below* your `cout` insertions if you want to see them interactively with each set of input.

Comment: It might be worth putting all those reads into a separate function. Here is an example structure I provided for another question that may (or may not) help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027674/readline-in-c/26027873#26027873

Comment: Put the `cin.ignore()` before the first `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code. you didnt give any command in while body to break the while.

(1) you have used cin.ignore(); function instead of this use this ( cin.ignore(256,'\n') ). This help to get empty buffer of cin for next input.
(2) You need to focus on which condition while loop should be break. I m here cnsidering on your 1st input variable title. in while loop first statement after while condition should be (a specific decision condition such as for title(Mr. Miss. Mrs.)) such if(title!="Mr."||title!="Miss."||title!="Mrs.") than break;
(3) for showing all input as output.. you should store them. If you dont want than, put all cout statements inside the while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string title;
   string url;
   string comment;
   double length = 0.0;
   int rating = 0;
   string sort_method;
   cin >> sort_method;

   while(getline(cin,title))
   {
       // use operator overloading
       if(title!="Mr."||title!="Mrs."||title!="Miss.")
            break;
       getline(cin, url);
       getline(cin, comment);
       cin >> length;
       cin >> rating;
       cin.ignore(256,'\n');
       cout << title << endl;
       cout << url << endl;
       cout << comment << endl;
       cout << length << endl;
       cout << rating << endl;
       cout<<"for quit press 'q'"<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Hope so this may help you...